# href returning another URL

Tags: php, laravel

After I click in the menu navigation (for exemple href='home') when i am in the view  *.../public/single/1* they send me to **.../public/single/home** and not **.../public/home**

Here is my code:

MENU LIST

```
<div class="header_content d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-start">
    <div class="logo"><a href="#"><span>m</span>a <span> B</span>ibli<span>o</span></a></div>
        <nav class="main_nav">
            <ul class="d-flex flex-row align-items-start justify-content-start">
                <li class="{{$home}}"><a href="home">Acceuil</a></li>
                <li class="{{$about}}"><a href="about">About us</a></li>
                <li class="{{$listing}}"><a href="listing">Produits</a></li>
                <li class="{{$blog}}"><a href="blog">Nouveauté</a></li>
                <li class="{{$contact}}"><a href="contact">Contactez nous!</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="submit ml-auto"><a href="#">Recherche >></a></div>
        <div class="hamburger ml-auto"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

WEB.PHP

```
Route::get('/single/{id}','AnnonceController@annonce');
Route::get('/home','PagesController@home');
Route::resource('home','AnnonceController');
```

And this is my controller:

```
public function annonce($id) {
    $annonce = DB::table('annonce')
        ->join('article', 'annonce.ID_ANNONCE', '=', 'article.ID_ANNONCE')
        ->join('photo_articles', 'photo_articles.ID_ARTICLE', '=', 'article.ID_ARTICLE')
        ->select('annonce.*', 'article.NOM_ARTICLE','PHOTO_ARTICLE')
        ->where('annonce.ID_ANNONCE',$id)
        ->get();

   return view('single')->with('annonce',$annonce);
}
```

Comment: That is how relative URLs work. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/urls for how to generate accurate URLs for your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because you giving href='home' which will add to your current URL , which means you are on single/1(route parameter) and when you click it will become single/home(parameter).

so give the full path.

I suggest you should use the route function of laravel and also give the name to your route like below

`Route::get('/home','PagesController@home')->name('myhome');`
see [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/urls#urls-for-named-routes) for naming route.

then call this in your blade like this
`{{route('myhome')}}`

Answer (score 0):

You return statement should be like this `return view('single',['id' => $id])->with('annonce',$annonce);`

**Note:** Please use relationship in Laravel instead of `DB::table`

```
public function annonce($id) {
    $annonce = DB::table('annonce')
        ->join('article', 'annonce.ID_ANNONCE', '=', 'article.ID_ANNONCE')
        ->join('photo_articles', 'photo_articles.ID_ARTICLE', '=', 'article.ID_ARTICLE')
        ->select('annonce.*', 'article.NOM_ARTICLE','PHOTO_ARTICLE')
        ->where('annonce.ID_ANNONCE',$id)
        ->get();

   return view('single',['id' => $id])->with('annonce',$annonce);
}
```